# C# VSTO outlook addin - modifying navigation pane

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2016

I am trying to create a VSTO Add In for Outlook. I have tried to search everywhere but have not found anything. I want to know if the following things are possible or not and if yes, how:

1) Show a Windows Form inside or below the navigation pane in the outlook explorer window.

2) I am loading a web view in a Custom Task Pane. I want to call a method in outlook when some action is performed in that web view.

Comment: VSTO is painful, IMHO. I used https://www.add-in-express.com to do what you're asking for and it works well. (No, I'm in no way affiliated to them).

Comment: Posting whatever I could find out on the questions that I had posted earlier:

1) Apparently, not possible to do 

2) Again not possible natively. I devised a workaround using sockets.  I've a small server running in the background. When the web link is clicked inside the webview, it sends a request to the locally running server to generate an event in the .net panel. Not perfect but works